# JPA relationship ManyToMany with additional parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, mariadb

I want to make a JPA relationship ManyToMany with additional parameters on the table of relationship and a different primary key, and I'm still getting the error below: Can someone help me please? Thank you

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'order INT(11) not null auto_increment,
>           idPoint INT(11),
>           idPolygo' at line 2

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Point")
    public class Point implements Serializable{
               @Id
               @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
               @Column(name = "idPoint", columnDefinition = "INT(11)", nullable = false)
               private int idPoint;

               @Column(name = "lat", columnDefinition = "DOUBLE(10,8) ", nullable = true)
               private double lat;

               @Column(name = "lng", columnDefinition = "DOUBLE(10,8)", nullable = true)
               private double lng;
                //relationship OneToMany with table PolygonHasPoint
                @OneToMany(mappedBy="point")
                private Set<PolygonHasPoint> polygonHasPoint;
        }
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Polygon")
    public class Polygon implements Serializable{
            //primary key : idPolygon
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
            @Column(name = "idPolygon", columnDefinition = "INT(11)", nullable = false)
            private int idPolygon;

            //relationship OneToMany with table PolygonHasPoint
            @OneToMany(mappedBy="polygon")
            private Set<PolygonHasPoint> polygonHasPoint;
   }

   @Entity(name="Point_Polygon")
   @Table(name = "Polygon_Point")
   public class PolygonHasPoint implements Serializable{

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "order", columnDefinition = "INT(11)", nullable = false)
        private int order;


        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "idPoint", columnDefinition = "INT(11)", nullable = true)
        private Point point;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "idPolygon", columnDefinition = "INT(11)", nullable = true)
        private Polygon polygon;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

'order' is a restricted keyword in most RDMBS. Try "position" or "sort".

You could try defining with backticks if you really want to stay with current name:

```
@Column(name = "`order`", columnDefinition = "INT(11)", nullable = false)
private int order;
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much I didn't pay attention to that, you saved my time!